# Serve web application in china

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cdn

Currently we has Ec2 Instance in north Virgina. Same application we need to serve for China users. How we can achieve this with Cloudfront.

Comment: Your question is lacking in detail and impossible to answer except to say go and read the excellent documentation for AWS Cloudfront supplied by Amazon themselves

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to provide access to Chinese customers in China with AWS resources in China, then you will need a separate AWS Chinese account. The first requirement to apply is an office in China. Expect delays to get an account approved.

If you do not have an office in China, then your Chinese customers will use the Internet to access your CloudFront content outside of China. The Chinese government has pretty strict controls on who can provide Internet content.